# Plot multiple lines in python/basemap

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I have just started learning python/matplotlib/basemap and could really use some help. How do you plot multiple lines?

Say my data looks something like:

```
[(lat1,lon1) (lat2,lon2) (lat3,lon3)]
[(lat1,lon1) (lat2,lon2) (lat3,lon3)]
[(lat1,lon1) (lat2,lon2) (lat3,lon3)]
...
```

I want to plot a separate line for each line in my data. What I get with my code, however, is that is connects the last point in the previous line to the first in the current line. Can anyone help me fix this?
Thank you!

EDIT:
Here is what I have for code:

```
for page in files:
    file = open(dir + '/' + page)
    for line in file:
       lines = line.split()
       time = lines[0]
       lon = lines[1]
       lat = lines[2]
       lon_float = float(lon)
       lat_float = float(lat)
       lats.append(lat_float)
       lons.append(lon_float)
    x,y = m(lons, lats)
    m.plot(x,y,'D-')
plt.show()
```

I want to plot one line for every file (which has multiple lat/long pairs) Also, m is my Baseplot instance

Comment: ah, see my edited answer.  We were barking up the wrong tree;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not clearing `lats` and `lons` so every time through the file loop you are accumulating the points.

```
for page in files:
    file = open(dir + '/' + page)
    lats = []
    lons = []
    for line in file:
        ...
```

EDIT: Completely re-wrote answer

Comment: To help with clarity, the zip statements could be split into two lines: `lats, lons = zip(*data)` followed by `plt.plot(lons, lats)`. I think the order of the lons and lats may need to be switched for @tcaswells example to work (but I can never remember with confidence).

Comment: Yes! That is exactly what I wanted! Thank you so much!! That make so much sense!